# Excel VBA Loop Through a PivotTable and perform calculation

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a PivotTable that automatically refreshes every time I refresh a data set to our mySQL database in our office.

My Excel file launches a query against the mySQL database and returns a data table, and I have two PivotTables on separate sheets that will automatically update every time that is done. My code for that is below:

```
Sub UpdatePivots()
    ' This sub is intended to update all pivot charts in the by switching to the appropriate
    ' worksheet, locating the appropriate pivot table, and updating them.

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim PT As PivotTable

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets '<~~ Loop all worksheets in workbook
        For Each PT In ws.PivotTables        '<~~ Loop all pivot tables in worksheet
            PT.PivotCache.Refresh
        Next PT
    Next ws
End Sub
```

What I am looking to do calculate a YIELD for some of the fields in the Pivot Table. The table currently looks like this below:[image: Example Sheet]

As you can see, I added in the "YIELD" column automatically and simply did an:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Pass / Fail",$B$5,"Job ID","Job 1","Pass / Fail","Pass")/GETPIVOTDATA("Pass / Fail",$B$5,"Job ID","Job 1")
```

Ideally, what I would like to do is add to my UpdatePivots() macro to automatically calculate the yield (Pass / Grand Total) for each of the rows listed.

This table is subject to change in size - sometimes I am looking at only 3 jobs in a given month (like September so far), other times my boss wants me to run this report for an entire year where I can have an upwards of 100 jobs. So I would like to use some pseudo code that might look like this:

```
Cell F6.Text = YIELD
<Apply Pivot Table Formatting to Cell F6>

for each row in pivottable {

    Cell Fx.Value = Pass / Grand Total

}
```

Can anybody help me do that? I have tried brainstorming on paper, but don't even know where to start.

PS - How can I get the Pivot Table to stop that terrible formatting, and to keep my grayed cells? I want to eventually add in charts.

Thank you!!

Comment: why don't you add a calculated field in the pivot table with your yield formula?

Comment: @nutsch I tried, and get an error stating "References, Names, Arrays, are not supported in Pivot Table formulas"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code satisfies my need:

```
Sub CalculateYield()

    k = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 9 To k
        Cells(r, 6).Formula = "=" & Cells(r, 3).Address(False, False) & "/" & Cells(r, 5).Address(False, False)
    Next

End Sub
```